# Populating a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
    AuthorID  Year  citations
0          1  1995         86
1          2  1995         22
2          3  1995         22
3          4  1995         22
4          5  1995         36
5          6  1995         25
```

and another dataframe which I created and initialized all to zeros `df2` where each index represents an `AuthorID` from `df`:

```
         1994  1995  1996  1997  1998  1999  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  
1           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
2           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
3           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
4           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
5           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
6           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now what I want to do is iterate through `df` and add the citation value to its correct location in the second matrix. So if I am to fill up `df2` based on what I have above, it would look like this:

```
         1994  1995  1996  1997  1998  1999  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  
1           0     86     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
2           0     22     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
3           0     22     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
4           0     36     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
5           0     25     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   
6           0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

This is very simply put.

Now what I have done is the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df2.iloc[row[0]][row[1]] = df2.iloc[row[0]][row[1]] + row[2]
```

But it keeps giving me the following:

```
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

So I tried:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df2.at[row[0], row[1]] = df2.at[row[0], row[1]] + row[2]
```

and it gives me:

```
ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers
```

I also tried `df.iat` but that also didn't work.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. When I check `df.dtypes` they all returned `int64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why cant you just pivot the first data frame like this

```
>> df.pivot(index='AuthorID', columns='Year', values='citations')
```

This will bring all the years as columns and index will be your `AuthorID`.

Comment: I really want to make some calculation with the citation not put it as is as I iterate. But i figured explaining it this way might be simpler. What I really want is to spread the value of the citations evenly over the 3 years that follow its publishing year. So authorid=1, year=1995, citation=86, will add 86/3 in df2[1]['1996'], df2[1]['1997'], and df2[1]['1998']

Answer (score 1):

So, here's a long way to do what you want : assign 1/3rd values to other years than 1995 for each AuthorID.

`x` is your data-frame.

We will add years: 1996, 1997 and 1998 for each AuthorID below and store in `y` data-frame.

```
y = pd.DataFrame([[i, y, 0] for y in [1996,1997,1998] for i in x.AuthorID], columns=['AuthorID','Year','citations'])
z = x.append(y)
```

Below, we will assign 1/3 value of 1995 citations to all the other years for the same author.

```
for id in z['AuthorID'].unique():
    condition = (z['AuthorID']==id) & (z['Year']>1995)
    citation2 = (z.loc[(z['Year']==1995) & (z['AuthorID']==id),'citations']/3).values
    z['citations'][condition] = citation2

In [1541]: z.pivot(index='AuthorID', columns='Year', values='citations')
Out[1541]: 
Year      1995       1996       1997       1998
AuthorID                                       
1           86  28.666667  28.666667  28.666667
2           22   7.333333   7.333333   7.333333
3           22   7.333333   7.333333   7.333333
4           22   7.333333   7.333333   7.333333
5           36  12.000000  12.000000  12.000000
6           25   8.333333   8.333333   8.333333
```

Comment: this would work if I only had years 1995 to 1998, which isn't the case. What is wrong with iterating through the first df and adding to the second df2? I want to be able to be flexible to do other calculations if needed. I don't know why basic looping just won't work?